# Name of deleted FB app still appearing

Tags: ios, facebook, native

Using my FB account I created an FB app for use by an iOS native app to post to the user's wall. This FB app was for development/testing purposes. Now that development is nearing completion, I have asked the client to create a new FB app using his own FB account, for the iOS app to use. The client has done so, and I have also deleted my development FB app, and switched the iOS app to use the production FB app's ID and secret.

However, now when the iOS app posts to FB, the post still shows something like the following, below the post content: "Get <Development App Name> - 9 minutes ago via <Production App Name>". I have not idea why the development app name is still appearing, even though it has already been deleted, and the iOS app has switched to the production app's ID and secret. The only thing that links the two is that the iOS app's bundle ID and app store ID are the same. Anyone else seen this before?

Comment: What app ID are the posts attributed to? the one you think is deleted or the other one? Click the app attribution link on the post to check, it's beside the 'X minutes ago' at the bottom of the post, and will say 'Via <appname>'

Comment: For the "via" part (right of the "X minutes ago"), it correctly gives the name of the new app. It is the "Get" part (left of the "X minutes ago") that still shows the name of the old (and deleted) app, and it is also linked using the URL specified in the deleted app, not the new one.
Initially I thought perhaps it might take some time for the changes to be synced/propagated through the FB servers or something, but it's been >24hrs, which is kinda long.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'Get' part - are you sure this isn't an action link you're manually inserting into the post you're making and have accidentally left the old content in the API call?

Comment: OK, below the contents of the post, there's a line that looks like this: "Like · Comment · Get Keat's Testing App · 33 minutes ago via Keat's Actual App". E.g. if I used the Pulse news reader app on my iPad to share a news article, the post on my wall would have "Get Pulse - x minutes ago via Pulse", and "Get Pulse" would be linked to the Pulse app in the App Store. In my case, "Keat's Actual App" is correct - it is the name of the new FB app that's been created. But the "Get" part is still using the name of the old/deleted app and it's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about an Action link attached to the post, not to Facebook's text attributing the Post to your app. This isn't something in your app settings, it's part of the API call you made to Facebook to make the post.
E.g. on this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH64u.jpg - the 'Donate Now' link is added by the app itself in the API Call which makes the post

Check the code you're using to actually make the post and check you don't have the old app name and URL in the API call

Comment: Oh man, really dumb mistake. I'm using the ShareKit library, and I edited the ID & secret, but did not change the app name and URL. :( Excuse me while I kick myself now. Sorry for the trouble...